# how to use list as args in yacs?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am using yacs to parse my args. One of my config is list,

```
dataset:
  - Set5
  - Set14
```

now I want to use other dataset, but I can't just

```
python train.py dataset [Set5,Urban100]
```

so, how can I using list as args?